# How to fix context manually or with a tool?

Tags: adb, twrp, system

I've installed the new version of MIUI 14 from the MIUI 13 on my Xiaomi device mi 10 ultra, cas codename, after that i receive a system alert about battery and performance application, the issues are about context, here the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.utils.PackageUtil.getPackageNameByUid(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.millet.MilletUidObserver.getPkgNameByUid(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.millet.MilletUtils.setPkgData(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.FrozenAppController$AppStateFrozenControl.frozenAppLater(Unknown Source:57)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.FrozenAppController$AppStateFrozenControl.handleEvent(Unknown Source:83)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.FrozenAppController$AppStateFrozenControl.frozenAppNow(Unknown Source:183)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.FrozenAppController$AppStateFrozenControl.handleEvent(Unknown Source:262)
    at com.miui.powerkeeper.controller.FrozenAppController$8.run(Unknown Source:20)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Unknown Source:182)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Unknown Source:82)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(Unknown Source:28)
```

So my question is how to fix this context system error manually using chcon or restorecon or any other method?

Comment: This is a bug of an app that is part of your system. You can not change such apps. What you can try is to clear app data of the affected [system] app (e.g. if the app data does not match the new app version). If that does not help consider it a bug, report it to 
Xiaomi and hope that it will be fixed with the next update.

Comment: I've try to check in settings>applications but i can't find the app to clear the cache as you tell..... any suggestion where to find it for clearing the cache?

Comment: The error is about [Android App Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context), not [Security Context](http://www.selinuxproject.org/page/SELinux_contexts). Only the developers of the app (`com.miui.powerkeeper`) can fix the bug.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for your hint i've solved the problem, the alert window with the mentioned bugs is not popping up anymore, the path to solve the problem was: settings>applications, tap the three dots up right on the screen corner> show all application>battery and performance application>clear all data.